# How can I make the git repository the same as the folder on my computer

Tags: git, github, jekyll

I've recently started using GitHub and created a blog there. I made several pushes and now when I inspect it on the GitHub, I can see several files that I've deleted from my local machine. Is there any ways to delete them from GitHub?

Comment: What does `git status` output?

Comment: @maartencls On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working directory clean

Comment: I would try to do a `git pull` and delete the files and make sure to commit these changes and push the branch

Comment: Can you give your github url ?

Comment: Did you use `git rm` for the deleted files before committing? You may have removed the files from your working directory, but if you do not remove them from the index they will still be included in your commits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove them from Git's index using `git rm /path/to/file`.

When you then run `git status` it should show the file you deleted. You can then commit your change as usual.